# Laravel Directory changing issue

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I earlier had a installed Laravel in public_html, the login was with the example.com/login. but due to new requirement I had to move the Laravel files into the subfolder. Now the /var/www/html has mainly the Wordpress site which does get open successfully. When I open Laravel via 
http://example.com/larvel-sub-folder/public 
it opens up the login. When I enter credentials it redirects to http://example.com/do-login (Error 404).

Now which is the exact specific file url is to be changed, I tried to search for few solution but end up finding none of them.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the `APP_URL` key under the `.env` file, which should be under your Laravel root dir, to reflect the correct path to the Laravel site. If you have a `.htaccess` file handling the rewrite then you may have to edit that as well.

Under the `.htaccess` file you may have to adjust `RewriteBase /` to better reflect the subdir laravel is now in.

Also look too see if $redirectTo is set under your AuthController.php, if so then adjust to fit your needs if not you could try setting it to fit your needs, such as `protected $redirectTo = '/larvel-sub-folder/';`

Comment: I have changed the APP_URL still the issue persists. I do have the access to .htaccess file but I don't know what's the exact point to rewrite.

Comment: See my last edit, it may help you as well. The rewrite handles url routing so that things like http://example.com/larvel-sub-folder/login work correctly

Comment: That was a nice input. I tried RewriteBase / and RewriteBase laravel both of these command entered in .htaccess lead to no output at example.com/laravel/public , when I removed the RewriteBase the site login screen came back again. still when I login it redirects to example.com/do-login

Comment: I did see the AuthController.php it has no variable of $redirectTo